# How to set puppeteer browser to variable?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I try to launch one browser and use it as it need, but i don't know how to set it to variable.

```
// return promise
puppeteer.launch()
```

this :

```
// It's not working
let bro;
puppeteer.launch()
    .then(res => bro = res);
```

this:

```
//It's not working too
let bro;
puppeteer.launch()
    .then(res => bro = res);
while (bro === undefined) {

}
bro.newPage();
```

please tell me how to launch browser once and use it as need :

```
//
let bro
// launch browser
bro.newPage()
...
```

For example in react i can call async function

```
axios.post("/postOnePage", data)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.setState({onePageCount: res.data.wordCount});
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

set result to variable and use it as it need

Answer (score 6):

Its pretty simple if you use **`async/await`**:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
```

**NOTE**: *wrap it inside a **`async` function*** .
Basically `puppeteer.launch()` returns a promise which resolves to browser instance. So you can simply initialise a **variable** as above to get the **browser**. With **`then`** it will be a bit of a mess I guess and you have to work within the **`then`** blocks.

```
const browser = puppeteer.launch();
browser.then((brw) => {
    const page = brw.newPage();
    page.then(pg => {
        pg.goto('https://example.com').then(() => {
            pg.screenshot({
                path: 'example.png'
            }).then(() => {
                brw.close();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You can also refer to the [Puppeteer API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.4.0/docs/api.md)  . The documentation is very good with examples. Hope it further helps.

**Edit 1:** 
Sample working example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getScreenshot(page) {
    await page.screenshot({
        path: 'exampleShot.png'
    });
}

async function newPageAndScreenshot(browser) {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.github.com');
    await page.screenshot({
        path: 'github.png'
    });
    //you can also call getScreenshot here.
    //await getScreenshot(page);
}

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
    await getScreenshot(page);
    await newPageAndScreenshot(browser);
    //Some other function calls may be.
    browser.close();

}

run();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: and i need to launch browser to each page load. I want to load browser and use it as it need in other functions

Comment: What is the issue with the current answer?

Comment: Can you please brief on exactly what you are looking for ?

Comment: You can open multiple pages on a single browser and also pass it to the functions. You can make a `async` function call  that initialises the browser for you every time you need it. Keep in mind since its all asynchronous, you work with the instances once the promise has resolved using either `then` call or using `async/await`.

Comment: @mayank1495 after function y write i call `browser.newPage();` and got error `TypeError: browser.newPage is not a function.`

Comment: The way you are using it, `browser` I guess is the returned promise. You chain it with `then` which accepts one parameter which then is the actual browser object. Like the code have written in the answer. `brw` is the actual object which has the `newPage` function.

Comment: @mayank1495 change question, add "sample" of what i whant to get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172499/discussion-between-asapo-kl-and-mayank1495).

Answer (score 1):

I tried your first version of your code i.e.

```
let bro;
puppeteer.launch()
    .then(res => bro = res);
```

and it is working, ONLY after using the keyword `await` like

```
let bro;
await puppeteer.launch()
    .then(res => bro = res);
```

Here's how my code is running

```
async function run(){
    let bro;
    await puppeteer.launch()
    .then(res => bro = res);

    const page = await bro.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://github.com/login');
    await bro.close();
}
run();
```

Another version of the same code

```
let bro;
    await puppeteer.launch()
                   .then(async browser => {
                    bro = browser;
                   });
```

Let me know if this works.

**Version 2**
Since node environment is asynchronous, you'll have to use alter the way you call functions and pass variables. Here's  the new code where browser varable is available outside run().

```
var bro;
async function run(){
    await puppeteer.launch()
    .then(res => bro = res);

    const page = await bro.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://github.com/login');

}

//another function
async function another(){
    console.log('2')
    const page = await bro.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://github.com');
    await bro.close();
}
run().then(() => another());
```

**NOTE**
close the browser using `bro.close()` in the last function you use it in

Comment: you write same thing as previews answer. I want to know how to get access to variable out of scope of async func. For example in your run function. How to get access to bro in next line after run(); ?

Comment: Read Version 2 in my answer. Now I think it works as you want. I ran it, it first opens a tab for first URL and then opens another tab in the same browser for second URL (in the another() function) @asapokL ...and yes it is using the same browser variable for both

Comment: First. Just run your cide and get error   `2
(node:6040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newPage' of undefined` Second. you just break one function into two. I can't do something until second page loading

Comment: I have run this code that's why I posted it and that's why I was able to tell what is happening. And I didn't break one function into two, I wrote one more function. First there was only `run()` handling one tab of the browser now there's one more function `another()` which lets you use the same browser variable in another function i.e. outside `run()` to open one more tab. So you have your solution for `how to use bro outside run() and use it as needed`. NOW this is another thing you have your own use case of how to use the variable which frankly your ques doesn't explain much about.

Comment: may be i didn't understand something but i can't use another function separate from run function. i will try later

Answer (score 0):

Please try `{}` in arrow function

```
// Try
let bro;
puppeteer.launch()
    .then(res => {bro = res});
```

Or

```
// Try
const handleRes = (res) => {
    // do something with res here
}
puppeteer.launch()
    .then(handleRes);
```

Comment: "Please try {}"  change nothing. handleRes function also isn't work