# How to debug puppeteer-extra by adding a DEBUG environment variable to my google cloud functions?

Tags: typescript, debugging, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I am trying to set a DEBUG environment variable to debug a puppeteer-extra plugin in my cloud functions.

Their documentation says I need to set `DEBUG=puppeteer-extra,puppeteer-extra-plugin:* node myscript.js`
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra)

I have created an .env.yaml file in my root folder as stated here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#setting_runtime_environment_variables

and added

`DEBUG: puppeteer-extra,puppeteer-extra-plugin:* node myscript.js`

but I am unable to find which file to reference here.
How can I make the debugger work for the puppeteer-extra package?

Comment: Christian, yes, you may try the reference the file as below and also check the logs as mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppeteer looks for certain environment variables to aid its operations. If Puppeteer doesn't find them in the environment during the installation step, a lowercased variant of these variables will be used from the npm config.You can see the package's logs by setting the DEBUG=puppeteer-extra-plugin:session env variable.

Example: `DEBUG=puppeteer-extra-plugin:session npm test`

Convenience debug logger based on the [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) module. Will automatically namespace the logging output to the plugin package name.

toggle output using environment variables
`DEBUG=puppeteer-extra-plugin:<plugin_name> node foo.js`

to debug all the things:
`DEBUG=puppeteer-extra,puppeteer-extra-plugin:* node foo.js`

Example:
`this.debug('hello world')`
// will output e.g. 'puppeteer-extra-plugin:anonymize-ua hello world'
You can also capture console output and  listen for the console event. This is also handy when debugging code in

```
page.on('console', msg => console.log('PAGE LOG:', msg.text()));
await page.evaluate(() => console.log(`url is ${location.href}`));
```

See the core [Puppeteer-Extra Plugin](https://github.com/berstend/puppeteer-extra/tree/master/packages/puppeteer-extra-plugin) docs for additional information
Here is an example of [similar use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660731/how-to-set-puppeteer-browser-to-variable)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I had installed the debug package (though I didn't know it would work automatically). However I didn't understand what to write instead of foo.js. 

Do I need to reference the index.ts file like this : 
`DEBUG=puppeteer-extra,puppeteer-extra-plugin:* node index.ts`